# How to break calculation into two doubles and a char in c++

Tags: c++, calculator

I have a calculation in a string that is in the format of `x operator y`. How do I break this string up into two doubles for the numbers and a char for the operator?

Comment: `x` and `y` are numbers? or identifiers?

Comment: numbers and i want to split them up into double variables. Sorry for the question from a c++ noob

Comment: will this string vary in spaces? e.g. 1+2 or 1 +2 or 1 + 2

Comment: @Need4Sleep no, ive specifically told the user not to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

does this work for you?

```
string line = "1 operator 2";
stringstream ss(line);
double n1, n2;
string op;
ss >> n1;
ss >> op;
ss >> n2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to either parse the string, or tokenise it - splicing the string into individual pieces of data:

> 1. Parse string
> 2. Find data
> 3. Extract data
> 4. Convert to x & y to doubles
> 5. According to the operator do ... with x and y. (using a switch statement for example)

Two methods I propose could easily solve your problem. You could simply find the '+' character, and then get the LEFT of that character being x, and get to the RIGHT of that character which will be y. Then convert those extracted strings to doubles. Note: this would only be acceptable if there is ONLY ONE 'x operator y' in a string. otherwise you could potentially *grab* more than you want.

And then there is also another method using Binary Trees. Essentially you can make a calculator with a *Binary tree*, although it is quite advanced, and I wouldn't recommend it to you as of yet. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree

A commented example using a the first proposed solution:

```
#include <iostream> //used for std::cout
#include <string>   //used for std::string
#include <sstream>  //used to convert a std::string to a double
#include <cctype>   //used for checking if a character is a digit(0-9.)

int main() 
{
    //declare the source string to parse
    std::string source = "2+6";

    //output variables
    //operator is a keyword, so just use op.
    char op=' ';     
    double x=0, y=0;

    //parse source. iterate through each character starting at 0 (first character)
    for(int i = 0; i < source.size(); i++) {

        //check to see if its a character - ie if its not a number or . its an operator!
        //(can be any *character* really - however must be only *1 character* long) and it must also not be a space.
        if(!isdigit(source[i] || ' ')) {

            //create the strings to put the copied data in
            std::string xs, ys; //x and y strings

            //get the left and right of the operator
            //you could use a for loop, your choice.

            //copy before the operator.
            xs = source.substr(0, i);

            //get the operator
            op = source[i]; // by using the [i] - will just get a character from a string at [..]

            //skip the operator by adding 1 - get the right hand side
            ys = source.substr(i+1, source.size()-1);

            //create the string stream used for converting the data to a double (its like std::cout and std::cin - uses the << and >>)
            //use the stringstream xxs(..) <- to initialise the stringstream with our string above. 
            std::stringstream xss(xs); //xss = xs string
            std::stringstream yss(ys); //'   ' '  '

            //now the string stream does the work for us. just feed the xss & yss string streams(which are our x & y strings) into the doubles using the >> operator, converting the data types.
            xss >> x; //string TO double
            yss >> y;

            //don't want to search for any more characters now. finish up.
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "x  = " << x  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "op = " << op << std::endl;
    std::cout << "y  = " << y  << std::endl;

    std::system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

and without the comments if you just want to see the bare code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream> 
#include <cctype>  

int main()
{

    std::string source = "2+6";
    char op=' ';     
    double x=0, y=0;

    for(int i = 0; i < source.size(); i++) {
        if(!isdigit(source[i]) || ' ') {

            std::string xs, ys;

            xs = source.substr(0, i);
            op = source[i];
            ys = source.substr(i+1, source.size()-1);

            std::stringstream xss(xs);
            std::stringstream yss(ys); 

            xss >> x;
            yss >> y;

            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "x  = " << x  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "op = " << op << std::endl;
    std::cout << "y  = " << y  << std::endl;

    std::system("pause");


    return 0;
}
```

This code works with no spaces, or spaces, and can be expanded upon- instead of finding a single character as the operator, find 1-3 characters. Hope I helped :)

Comment: upvoted u and would love to have accepted ur answer, but the other guy got there first. sorry and all that ;)